# Difference between over sampling and upsampling and between SMOTE and over_sampling.SMOTE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, resampling, imblearn

This question is a bit of paranoia, as in google the search results gets mixed by the audio and Fourier transform etc.

1. Specifically for python, when it comes to numeric data, is there a difference between oversampling and upsampling of the minority class?
2. I am using imblearn to oversample/upsample a minority class. I am currently using

   ```
   from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

   sm = SMOTE(random_state=12, ratio = 1.0)
   x_train_res, y_train_res = sm.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)
   ```

   but more recently, I came across

   ```
   sm = over_sampling.SMOTE(random_state=12, ratio = 1.0)
   x_train_res, y_train_res = sm.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)
   ```

   What is the difference?

Comment: For the 2nd question, you showed 2 codes, but they are identical except  how to import SMOTE class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

sm = SMOTE(random_state=12, ratio = 1.0)
```

and

```
import imblearn.over_sampling 

sm = over_sampling.SMOTE(random_state=12, ratio = 1.0)
```

Is identical. The only difference is how you access the SMOTE function in your code.

Comment: Can you give an example?